# How this javaScript code is work? after if condition

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

i do not understood, how this code working after `if(y in hash)` most complicated for me is `hash` is empty and i do not push any value in `hash` so what will happened behind the scene and `y in hash` what its meaning?

```js
var twoSum = function(nums, target) {

  const hash = {}
  // console.log(hash)
  
  for (const i in nums) {
    const x = nums[i];
    const y = target - x
    // console.log(y)
    if (y in hash)
      return [i, hash[y]]
    hash[x] = i
  }

}

let arr = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
console.log(twoSum(arr, 11))
```

Comment: It's checking if the key stored in `y` is a key in the `hash` object (or its prototype chain), you can ready about `in` [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in). You're adding keys (not pushing) to `hash` each time you do `hash[x] = i`

Comment: You should also be [using `for/of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration#for...of_statement) to iterate over an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> hash is empty and I do not push any value

`hash[x] = i` part add values to hash, because it is out of `if(y in hash)` condition

> `y in hash` what it's meaning?

As Nick Parsons mentioned in a comment "it's checking if the key stored in y is a key in the hash object (or its prototype chain)"